# SQL Dynamic Pivot Query With Multiple Subtotal

Tags: sql, t-sql

For below code, I able to create a dynamic pivot with subtotal.But I need to add one more subtotal column in this code . It has to be total of **NUM_TO_EXIT** values.As you can see picture 2, I used **NUM_TO_ENTER** within dynamic dates in my dynamic pivot but I could not able to merge just for the total values of **NUM_TO_EXIT**. I tried everything but could not able to do that. Appreciate for yor supports.I am using MSSQL 2008 R2.

```
  DIRECTIONAL_METRIC_ID ZONE_ID START_TIME  END_TIME    RECEIVED_TS STATUS  NUM_TO_ENTER    NUM_TO_EXIT DAY_OF_WEEK_ID  TIME_ID
436909  254 2016-02-06 10:00:00.000 2016-02-06 10:00:00.000 2016-02-06 10:00:00.000 1   195 195 7   300
436910  254 2016-02-07 10:00:00.000 2016-02-07 10:15:00.000 2016-02-07 10:15:00.000 1   195 195 7   300
436911  278 2016-02-01 10:00:00.000 2016-02-01 10:15:00.000 2016-02-01 10:15:00.000 1   95  95  7   300
436912  278 2016-02-02 10:00:00.000 2016-02-02 10:15:00.000 2016-02-02 10:15:00.000 1   95  95  7   300
436913  278 2016-02-03 10:00:00.000 2016-02-03 10:15:00.000 2016-02-03 10:15:00.000 1   95  95  7   300
```

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd4i4.png)

[Structe of DIRECTIONAL_METRIC TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHstW.png)

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dates') IS NOT NULL
drop table #Dates


SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR,START_TIME,106) AS [Date]
INTO #Dates
FROM dbo.DIRECTIONAL_METRIC
WHERE CAST(START_TIME as DATE) >=CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),101)
and CAST(START_TIME as DATE) < @mydate
AND DATEPART(HOUR,START_TIME) BETWEEN 9 AND 23
order by [Date]

DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + [Date] +']','[' + [Date] + ']')
FROM #Dates


DECLARE @GrandTotalCol  NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @GrandTotalCol = COALESCE (@GrandTotalCol + 'ISNULL ([' + [Date] +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + [Date]+ '],0) + ')
FROM #Dates 
ORDER BY [Date]
SET @GrandTotalCol = LEFT (@GrandTotalCol, LEN (@GrandTotalCol)-1)

DECLARE @qry varchar(4000)
SET @qry =

'
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()

SELECT *, ('+ @GrandTotalCol + ') 
AS [Grand Total] INTO #temp_MatchesTotal 
FROM 
(
        SELECT ZO.CODE AS KOD,
        convert(varchar, START_TIME, 106) AS [Date],
        SUM(NUM_TO_ENTER) AS NUM_TO_ENTER
        FROM  dbo.DIRECTIONAL_METRIC AS z INNER JOIN ZONE AS ZO ON z.ZONE_ID=ZO.ZONE_ID
        WHERE CAST(START_TIME as DATE) >=CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),101)
        and CAST(START_TIME as DATE) < @mydate
        and DATEPART(HOUR,START_TIME) between 9 and 23
        AND ZO.CODE IS NOT NULL
        group by ZO.CODE,convert(varchar, START_TIME, 106)
) P
PIVOT
( 
         SUM(NUM_TO_ENTER) 
         FOR  [Date] IN(' +@cols + ')
)
 AS pvt
ORDER BY KOD
SELECT * FROM #temp_MatchesTotal 
DROP TABLE #temp_MatchesTotal'


EXEC(@qry)
GO
```

Comment: This can be dramatically simplified if you post some sample data (not screen shots)

Comment: I tried to add but I do know the create a table

Comment: I can make that work.  A few momments

Comment: Appreciate but I hope demand is clear ..

Comment: Just to eliminate any assumptions, what would be the desired results on the sample data provided?

Comment: I need to put exit subtotals for the dynamic dates at the end of tableas I put a screen shot AS What I need